# Помощь с программой на Питон

Tags: python

Написать программу, которая считывает английский текст из файла и выводит его на экран, заменив каждую первую букву слов, начинающихся с гласной буквы, на прописную.

Comment: нет вашего кода.

Comment: Просто вообще не знаю, как работать  со строками/текстами на питоне, затем и обращаюсь

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html

Answer (score 1):

```
input = "An example of the program you talked about"
out = ""

lc = ' '
for ch in zip(input):
    if lc[0] == ' ' and (ch[0] in "aeiouy"):
        out += ch[0].upper()
    else:
        out += ch[0]
    lc = ch
    
print(out)
```

Вывод:

```
An Example Of the program You talked About
```

Вы имели ввиду так?